# How do I manage network folders in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, network-shares

For whatever reason I don't recall how the 'd2' folder shown below was established on my workstation.  Can someone please direct me to where such things are set?  I would like to remove it, but don't know how.  It's really difficult to be drawing a total blank on this.

This workstation has three internal hard drives: C, D, E.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can potentially open a command prompt or PowerShell window and enter the `net use` command.  It will show you the source UNC path of that drive.

Of course, you can always right-click the drive and choose `Disconnect`, also.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer as it seems correct, but oddly, after I posted this question, the network location disappeared, so I was actually at a loss to try out the proposed solution.  That's why it took so long to respond.  I will keep this in mind next I see this 'un-commanded' location show up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all of those drives are mapped drives to a local or network share.

As @Run5k mention you can open a command prompt and type `net use` which will list all the network shares accessed including your mapped drives.

However, if it is a local share in `File Explorer`, right-click on the "d2" folder and select `Properties`. Under the `General` tab you should see a `Target` field which tells you the address of the share.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Tcpa.png)

Also if you want to check which credentials were used to access the network share, then you can use the `Credential Manager` (under Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager), select `Windows Credentials` and look through the list for an entry matching the hostname of the share.

Comment: Thanks for your input as well, please note my comment above.